# How do I ask the Lisp compiler to ignore a (label-variety) function?

Tags: lisp, common-lisp, clisp

I've stared at Steele's *Common Lisp the Language* until I'm blue in the face, and still have this question.  If I compile:

```
(defun x ()
  (labels ((y ()))
    5))
(princ (x))
(terpri)
```

this happens:

```
home:~/clisp/experiments$ clisp -c -q x.lisp
;; Compiling file /u/home/clisp/experiments/x.lisp ...
WARNING in lines 1..3 :
function X-Y is not used.
Misspelled or missing IGNORE declaration?
;; Wrote file /u/home/clisp/experiments/x.fas
0 errors, 1 warning
home:~/clisp/experiments$
```

Fair enough.  So how do I ask the compiler to ignore function y?  I tried this:

```
(defun x ()
  (labels (#+ignore(y ()))
    5))
(princ (x))
(terpri)
```

and it worked:

```
home:~/clisp/experiments$ clisp -c -q y.lisp
;; Compiling file /u/home/clisp/experiments/y.lisp ...
;; Wrote file /u/home/clisp/experiments/y.fas
0 errors, 0 warnings
home:~/clisp/experiments$
```

but somehow I don't think that's what the warning is suggesting that I do.

What do I do?

Comment: Just for reference, `#+ignore` lets the reader skip the entire next form (unless a there is `ignore` in `*features*`, of course).

Comment: Ed Zachary.  That was my evil plan.  But the good plan outlined in the answer below prevailed.  :)

Comment: CLtl and CLtl2 are both outdated books, and would recommend them only to people interested in the history of lisp, rather than be used as references or learning material. For modern ANSI common lisp reading I would recommend both Practical Common Lisp by Peter Seibel and Land of Lisp by Conrad Barski.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

GNU CLISP is asking you to [`declare`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/s_declar.htm) the function to be [`ignore`d](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/d_ignore.htm#ignore).

```
(defun x ()
  (labels ((y ()))
    (declare (ignore (function y)))
    5))
```

Alternatively (especially if this is the result of a macro expansion where it depends on the user whether `y` is actually used or not),

```
(defun x ()
  (labels ((y ()))
    (declare (ignorable (function y)))
    5))
```

(Wherever you are expected to write `(function y)`, you are free to use the reader abbreviation `#'y` instead.)